# Storing Image as Javascript Object Attribute

Tags: javascript, object

I was wondering if it is possible to store an image as an attribute of a js object. For example, I currently have:

```
twitter = {h:35, w:35, x:0, y:0, src: "./twitter.png"};
tw = new Image;
tw.src = twitter.src;
```

and then later in the program

```
context.drawImage(tw, twitter.x, twitter.y, twitter.w, twitter.h);
```

but I was wondering if the image src can be combined into the twitter object, so that it can be called like so

```
context.drawImage(twitter.src, twitter.x, twitter.y, twitter.w, twitter.h);
```

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: How about creating a function that creates/assembles an <img /> tag with src as twitter.src and just put in the other attributes in style="" ?

Comment: `context.drawImage(new Image().src=twitter.src, twitter.x, twitter.y, twitter.w, twitter.h);` is worth a shot

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `new Image` returns an object, and you can have any object as a property value. So try this:

```
twitter = {h:35, w:35, x:0, y:0, src: "./twitter.png"};
tw = new Image;
tw.src = twitter.src;
twitter.src = tw;
context.drawImage(twitter.src, twitter.x, twitter.y, twitter.w, twitter.h);
```

Comment: But is it possible to eliminate lines 2-4 altogether? And instantiate the image inside the twitter declaration?

Comment: You can instantiate the image as follows `twitter = {h:35, w:35, x:0, y:0, src:"./twitter.png", image: new Image}` but you will still need to set the image source at some point using `twitter.image.src = twitter.src`

Comment: that's perfect thanks! i have now trimmed it to `tw = {w:35, h:35, x:0, y:0, src: "./twitter.png", img: new Image}; 
 tw.img.src = tw.src;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use canvas's `toDataURL()` method to get the raw base64 bytes of the image and store that in the object